# python how can I print the item in a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

the problem I'm having is that when I try to print what's inside the list I get "True" instead of what the item is.

Here is the code I have:

```
    foods = []

    while food := input("enter foods ") !="exit":
        foods.append(food)
    
    for food in foods: 
        print(food)
```

Comment: just use parens to designate priority: `while (food := input("enter foods ")) != "exit"`. Better yet, avoid the walrus operator altogether.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foods = []

    while food := input("enter foods "):
        if food == "exit":
            break
        foods.append(food)
    
    for food in foods: 
        print(food)
```

you can try something like this

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this:

```
def list_creator():
    while (food := input("Enter food: ")) != "exit":
        yield food

foods = [i for i in list_creator()]


for food in foods: 
    print(food)
```

But yes, as was said in comments, your main problem was caused by not encapsulating your variable assignment in ().